# Best way to have a multi-purpose service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

Okay, here goes...  I am new to android programming and am in desperate need of direction.

My end result in mind is to be able to send requests to my `service` and depending on WHAT is requested, have it perform different actions.

**Example 1:** User presses a refresh button in an activity, which downloads information and then displays it it.

**Example 2:** User navigates to a login fragment in an activity where he can input his user name and password.  His currently saved information is displayed beforehand.

**Example 3:** User presses widget, which downloads information and then displays some information in the widget.

Hopefully I've gotten my idea across;  sending consuming tasks to a service, with the ability to update whatever display currently being worked on.
With the `services'` task being dependant on what is being asked of it (service: do I download? do I fetch login info? do I fetch some other information?), it ***must*** know how to proceed, once started... which leads me to my question:

**How do I tell my service which task to perform after it is called?**
Also, but less importantly, **what is the best, most code-efficient way to update views (widget, activity)?**

**Background information:**

- I have decided to use a service to facilitate both the widget and
  Activities.
- The service performs demanding tasks (downloads, database
  fetching/saving, and more) on an `AsyncTask`.
- I am calling my service as follows: 
  `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkerService.class);
  getActivity().startService(intent);`

Comment: can you bind the service or do you have to send a broadcast to communicate with the service?

Comment: I can bind it.  Would that be the best way of accomplishing my goals?  How would I then go about things after binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [BoundService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

> A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. A bound service allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

You have two ways of creating a BoundService:

1) Using a Binder - This is probably what you want to do.

> If your service is private to your own application and runs in the
>   same process as the client (which is common), you should create your
>   interface by extending the Binder class and returning an instance of
>   it from onBind(). The client receives the Binder and can use it to
>   directly access public methods available in either the Binder
>   implementation or even the Service. This is the preferred technique
>   when your service is merely a background worker for your own
>   application. The only reason you would not create your interface this
>   way is because your service is used by other applications or across
>   separate processes.

2) Using a Messanger

Remember that the service runs in the UI (main) thread. If you do long lasting operations you should create a background thread.

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a Binder looks to be what I need.  I'd have to wait for the methods in the service to finish before I update views... so I'd put that code in the service, right?

Comment: When the methods finish you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to notify the `Activity` about the change or maybe an EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: An example of multiple receivers would be nice.  I think I understand everything else. :)

Comment: btw use LocalBroadcastManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html